# Fabric.js - Saving snapshots of animation

Tags: html, animation, canvas, fabricjs, capture

I am using fabric.js to create some animations.

Now I would like to create a gif of the animation, so would like a "canvas capture" at 20 fps.  ie 20 pngs for every second.  I can then convert the pngs to a gif using convert.

I am running the animation on the server using node.js.

Question: How can I save the pngs as the animation is running?  It does not have to be written or processed real time as its only running on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a it like this.

```
var blob_array = new FormData(), png_index = 0;

function canv2blob(canv) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    canv.getElement().toBlob(function(blob) {
      resolve(blob);
    },'image/png',0.8); //0.8 is quality. keep it as you like
  });
}

function process_blob(canv){
 canv2blob(canv).then(function(blob){
     blob_array.append(png_index,blob);
 });
}
```

then in the `onChange` event of every fabric animation, call the function to create a `FormData` object containing png blobs which you can post to server.

```
onChange: function(){ 
          canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
          process_blob(canvas);
          png_index++;
      },
```